# How long a distributed build valid when share via hockey(App Center) or Fabric?

Tags: ios, build, google-fabric, hockeyapp, testfairy

I mostly use either `TestFairy` or `Diawi` account to share my iOS builds to the clients. Diawi's shared build goes expire after a week, but Testfairy's builds stay valid so long. And I just start exploring the other way of both these, those are

1. Fabric
2. Hockey SDK which will gonna migrate to App center very soon.

I explore a lot to get to know how long build will be valid if I share with either App Center or Fabric or there is no expiration time limit?

Please share if anyone know the expiration time limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an iOS app, the distribution should be valid till the time your provisioning profile / certificate you signed it with is valid. And Android app will be valid as long as it is installed on a compatible version of Android, there is no expiration on it.

This is mainly true for fabric, and I can only imagine that it's also true for hockey app (not 100% sure on this though).

Also, a point to note, beta by Crashlytics (Fabric) too is going to migrate to App Distribution in Firebase soon.